# Android Kotlin - find in MutableList and set condition

Tags: android, kotlin, mutablelist

This is the code for changing a value in a mutable list in case it is found:

```
vids?.find { it.id == 2 }?.iLike = true
```

But how to set a condition in case it wasn't found? I know how to do this in for loops so don't answer with that :D

Comment: `But how to set a condition in case it wasn't found?`??

Comment: The `find` returns `null` if no match is found, so the chained safe call `?.` should handle that, did you mean anything else?

Comment: @AnimeshSahu oh ok I didn't know that it returns null in case not found, your comment could have been used as answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to validate if it's found and then return

```
vids?.find { it.id == 2 }?.let {
    it.iLike = true
} ?: run {
    //do something
}
```

Just a clarification, you are not changing the value of the element because the list is mutable but because the attribute on the type of the collection is mutable. The attribute `iLike` is mutable that is why you can change it, not because of the mutable list.